# How can I forward all old emails from my GMail Sent folder to another email address?

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail account which I will close. I just realized that there are a bunch of emails in the Sent folder which I would like to retain. Is there an easy way to forward them all to another email address?

Comment: Is it another Gmail account you want to add them to?

Comment: No. I no longer wish to use Gmail, or [any Google products at all](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187982/how-can-i-escape-google).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Thunderbird might be a good option for you.

#### Thunderbird

“Thunderbird is a free and open source email, newsfeed, chat, and calendaring client, that’s easy to set up and customize. One of the core principles of Thunderbird is the use and promotion of open standards – this focus is a rejection of our world of closed platforms and services that can’t communicate with each other. We want our users to have freedom and choice in how they communicate.”

### Add Gmail as IMAP

1. Add your current Gmail account as an IMAP account (not POP) in [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/).
2. Customize synchronization settings in Thunderbird Great information here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization
3. Optionally, export your mail.

### Exporting Mail

You can install an **add-on** for Thunderbird to export mail such as: [importexporttools-ng](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/)